# How to close file in Java and/or know where in my code some file is locked?

Tags: java, file, file-locking

Apparently I am always calling `FileReader#close()` and `FileWriter#close()`, but some of my files remained locked by my own code.

How to

1) close file fully?

2) check, where in the code it was opened and not closed?

Comment: Calling `#close()` does close file *fully*. You may be missing some call because of badly-handled exception or something else.

Comment: So, how to find where I am forgetting to close file?

Comment: Dunno, but if you always use try-with-resources in the first place, there won't be such a problem.

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: My program is big. Somewhere in it I am forgetting to close the file. How to find this place in debugger?

Comment: And example of how you handling the file reading/writing is all that is needed...

Comment: @MadProgrammer You meant "An" example, didn't you?

Comment: @johnchen902 Yeah, but I didn't realise until now and I can't edit the comment :P

Comment: You can't 'find the place where you are forgetting to close the file'. It isn't there. *It's missing.* You just have to go through your code ensuring that opens are matched to closes and that closes happen in `finally` blocks to ensure they can't be bypassed by exceptions or `return` statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is vague and is missing context, so it makes it difficult to answer and encourages assumptions, never a good place to start from...

However, if you are doing something similar to...

```
try {
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(new File("..."));
    // Read file...
    fr.close();
} catch (IOException exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
}
```

Then if an exception occurs for some reason (or the code returns before it reaches the `close` statement), then `close` will never be called...

Prior to Java 7, one would typically do something like...

```
FileReader fr = nulll;
try {
    fr = new FileReader(new File("..."));
    // Read file...
} catch (IOException exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        // Avoid NullPointerException's
        if (fr != null) {
            fr.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception exp) {
    }
}
```

This ensures that regardless of what happens between the `try-catch`, `finally` will always be called and you can take steps to ensure that the resource is closed.

With Java 7, you can now take advantage of the ["try-with-resources"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) feature...

```
try (FileReader fr = new FileReader(new File("..."))) {
    fr = ;
    // Read file...
} catch (IOException exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
}
```

Which is basically a short-cutted version of the `try-catch-finally` example block.

If you are using the `FileLock` functionality, then you also need to ensure that you releasing the `FileLock` when you are done with, in a similar fashion to the `try-catch-finally` example above, but file locking will only ensure that different processes can't read/write the simultaneously, it doesn't protect you against multiple threaded access...